# Postman FCM Post to Specific Country

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

---

*I want to send FCM push notification using Postman may I know how could we can send this FCM notifications using postman to send it to particular country.*

Answer (score 0):

The only way to select a group of users (such as those in a particular country) in Firebase would be through Analytics.

Targeting messages to analytics audiences with Firebase is currently only possible in the Firebase console. There is no way to target Firebase audiences when sending message through the API.

Answer (score 0):

Requirement:

1. Connect firebase to your app. (1)
2. Have an firebase firestore or realtime database.(2)
3. Use firebase function.(3)
4. API listen request from Postman. (4)
5. Postman.

How it works.
(Postman to Devices).

1. Postman send {data} request to API(4)
2. handle API for save {data} to (2).
3. When (2) receive {data}. Firebase function identify that change and send {data} to devices through fcm-token.